# crystal reports: set up a dummy parameter as null

Tags: parameters, null, crystal-reports

I am a novice in Crystal Reports and I need help. I need to set up a parameter as a selection for null value. I, for example, created a dummy parameter called, "**No name**" and am trying to set it up as a null value in the dataset.

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once check the link.It shows how to create parameters and add default values like Null
https://kb.blackbaud.com/articles/Article/60683